# Error on MVC application debug : Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Starting form now, for the first time, I am getting this error when I start debugging my MVC application

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If
>   this application is hosted by a Web
>   Farm or cluster, ensure that
>    configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used
>   in a cluster.

Full stack trace

```
[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 127.0.0.1
    Port: 
    Referer: 
    Path: /Login/LogOn
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7
    ViewState: Fvq7WNUu+qCC00VbTIOTUuBvK4YHjxp3RubwsrFYW93hKlF7I4GLzaNHceRqjjJB0GwvRPWwlwE6brhAZAo+Mp191B/C+l8Dw/w7aQBDCpWGC3ox6hkSeZp10vbjm9eJFQZmGSPyC1rKYwApBBaz0Q==]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +198
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +14
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +274
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
   System.Web.Mvc.AntiForgeryDataSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken) +176
```

What does this means?

**Please note**: the error happens only during debug. When I deploy the app on local IIS everything works. It appears on the following code in my master page

```
<form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
</form>
```

Comment: Try clearing your browsers cache.

Comment: Just made without success. If I restart the computer everything works for half an hour and then the problem appear again...

Comment: Are you deploying your application in a load-balanced server? If not, check this link here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx.

Comment: @mallows98: the error, as I wrote, only happens during debug inside VS2010, it has never happened after a deploy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate reason why this is happening is because of the antiforgery cookie getting invalidated. Closing and reopening the browser should fix the issue. You could alternatively try deleting the cookie associated with your test site.

Now for the underlying cause, this usually happens either because

- you are in a web farm scenario and your various servers are not confiured the same way (but you're saying that's not the case)
- the application changes the autogenerated MAC because of changes you are making to your apps configuration
- you recently applied a patch to fix the Asp.Net ViewState encryption vulnerability (which changed the way that encryption is performed in asp.net).

Any of this sound familiar?

Comment: I would exclude the first point absolutely. In relation to the second and the thrid point I have installed the patches for the recent ASP.NET vulnerability through Windows Update as soon as they were available but the problem started to appear only in the latest days when I have added the Antiforgerytoken to my views.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue after patching the server to fix the ASP.NET vulnerability when viewed on machines without [KB2416471](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2416471) installed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your post. The problem seems not to regard me because it appears on Vista x64 where the patch you're referring to is not present. Anyway I have KB2416470, KB2416472 and KB2416473 installed through Windows Update

Comment: @Lorenzo yes, amazingly, we had this problem when viewing a site from machines which didn't have the patch installed.

Comment: That's interesting. But in my case there's something more strange: If I try to debug the application on my machine (VS2010, SQLEXPRESS) the problem appears. When, instead I am deploying locally always on my machine (IIS7, SQL EXPRESS) the problem does not appear...

Comment: @Lorenzo sounds like an update has conflicted with Cassini somehow.