# Validation of ViewState MAC Failed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if this is duplicate but I've been going crazy for the past two hours over this.

After changing the Master Page in ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application, I keep getting this familiar error when I try a postback without filling in the mandatory form elements which are validated by the server:

> "Validation of viewstate MAC failed.
>   If this application is hosted by a Web
>   Farm or cluster, ensure that
>    configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used
>   in a cluster."

The new page refers to a lot of jQuery code with lightboxes, superfish etc. Could that be a problem while doing a postback?

If I revert back to the original master, the error disappears and I'm able to validate form fields. Both masters are located in the same path.

I know a lot of other guys have faced this issue but I was unable to find anything which could help me.

Thanks.

**Edited and added**

After a little debugging, I've realized that a directive in the master page:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("menu", "nav"); %>
```

is creating the problem. The directive asks the "menu" action of the controller "nav" to inject a partial view Menu.ascx. If I delete this line from the new master page, everything works OK. My app's left bar navigation relies on this directive to work properly. Is there any way I can get around this? Very mysterious.

Comment: OK, this has been solved. I replaced the <form id="form1" runat="server"> form elements </form> to  <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %> form elements <% } %>. This did the trick. I have no idea why using Html helpers would be better than using good old tags. Anyone?

Comment: you are using MVC, so there should not be a form tag with runat, there is no viewstate in MVC.  You can use the regular form tag just don't use runat="server".

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Html.AntiForgeryToken() anywhere on this page?  Sometimes when I am testing locally with multiple different sites and / or port changes this will happen to me.  If it does I clear my browser cache and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did experienced the same problem [two days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111460/error-on-mvc-application-debug-start). :)

A simple restart of the box has worked in my case so I did'nt investigate further.